# How to detect current zoom level on map view?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a map view that draws radius overlay from current location. But for that, I need to know **current zoomlevel** on the map. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [getZoomLevel()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getZoomLevel%28%29) method of MapView class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function:

```
mapView.getZoomLevel()
```

Answer (score 1):

getZoomLevel() is deprecated now (v 6+)
Use getZoomLevelDouble() instead.

Answer (score 0):

In MapView Class, call 
method - getZoomLevel().
          It returns the current zoom level of the map.